# Proper way for getting annotations of Java-Methods in custom Sonar rules

Tags: java, sonarqube

I try to write a custom Sonar-rule (Java) and struggle with the proper way for getting annotation of invoked Java methods. 
This rule should detect illegal access to methods and fields marked as `@VisibleForTesting`. Accesing such elements from production code is illegal, but access from the same class is legal. 
My first approach is to implement `BaseTreeVisitor.visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocationTree)` and use the metadata of the belonging symbol:

- get annotations: `methodInvocationSymbol.metadata().annotations()`
- analyse the names of the symbols of each `AnnotationInstance` (annotations class) and its owner (annotations package)

This works great as long other classes invoke the method. When the call is made *inside the same class* - the annotations name and package are set to `!unknownSymbol!`.

I also tried an alternative approach: to analyse the `IdentifierTree` of the `AnnotationTree` (inside of `BaseTreeVisitor.visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocationTree))`, but I could not find the way how to get the package name of the annotation.

I use sonar-java-plugin 3.7.1 and sonar-plugin-api 5.1.

The code is commited in this [mvn / Eclipse project](https://github.com/arxes-tolina/sonar-plugins).
The `UnexpectedAccessCheckTest` contains 2 use-cases. The "InvokedFromOtherClass" works well. The `InvokedFromSameClass` passes the test, but it happens only by accident - the annotation is not correctly detected.
It produces this output:

```
[main] DEBUG d.t.s.p.vft.checks.IsAnAnnotation - Checking Annotation. 
    Expected [com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting] 
    got [.!unknownSymbol!]
```

The correct running use-case produces this:

```
[main] DEBUG d.t.s.p.vft.checks.IsAnAnnotation - Checking Annotation. 
    Expected [com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting] 
    got [com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting]
```

Do you have any hint for me?

Comment: Can you please precise the sonar-java plugin version you are using ? If I get your question correctly your problem is when you want to check a method invoked in the same source file as its declaration ? this first way you described should work, if not, then most probably, the method is not resolved. can you share a sample case that does not work ?

Comment: @benzonico Thanks for your quick answer! I use 3.7.1 of sonar-java-plugin and 5.1 of sonar-plugin-api

Comment: You shared code, but this is rather unclear, what _exactly_  is the pattern you want to detect and what does not work as expected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is prefered and should work for every method call, even within the same class.

If it does not work it probably means that the method invoked is not resolved from semantic (which is why the symbol is set to unknown, the analyzer has some bugs regarding method calls when generics are involved).
In order to point you out to the correct ticket, an example would be required.

Regarding your comment about the syntax tree : the identifier in the syntax tree won't contain information about the package (as its name gives it away, it concerns only *syntax* ;) ). However, you can use the following to find the type of the annotation from the source :

`annotationTree.annotationType().symbolType().is("com.mypackage.MyAnnotation")`

Make sure that the expected binary is in the Classpath while runnnig the scan (see `sonar.java.binaries` property, or usage of `maven-dependency-plugin` if you use Maven).

Comment: It does not seem to work that way, at least in my configuration.  In https://github.com/arxes-tolina/sonar-plugins  I commited `MisuseOfVisibleForTestingCheck` with a debug output. Running the `MisuseOfVisibleForTestingCheckTest` produces only
`[main] DEBUG d.t.s.p.v.c.MisuseOfVisibleForTestingCheck - VisibleForTesting found: false`
lines....
Any idea why it happens so?

Comment: The bytecode of the annotation you are trying to test should be available in the classpath of the analysis via `sonar.java.binaries` property

Comment: This clue helped me to understand, why in org.sonar.samples:java-custom-rules there is an extra execution of the maven-dependency-plugin :)