# How to detect class member (field) acces in Sonar Rules

Tags: java, sonarqube

While writing a Sonar-rule (Java), I could not find a way to detect an access to a class member. 
Example:

```
class SomeClass {
    Object field;
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();

    void method(){
        Objects.requireNonNull(instance.field);
    }

}
```

In this Example `SomeOtherClass.method()` accesses a package-protected member of SomeClass.
I could not find a suitable method of `org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.TreeVisitor` for detecting this.
My first guess was to use

```
BaseTreeVisitor.visitMemberSelectExpression(MemberSelectExpressionTree))
```

but it didn't worked as I expected.

I commited the code to https://github.com/arxes-tolina/sonar-plugins/
and implemented `UnexpectedAccessCheck.visitMemberSelectExpression(MemberSelectExpressionTree)` with debug output only. Running the test leeds to some lines on the console:

```
[main] DEBUG d.t.s.p.v.c.UnexpectedAccessCheck - visitMemberSelectExpression invoked. Name of the symbol of identifier: !unknownSymbol!
```

May be, that this question is related to 
[Proper way for getting annotations of Java-Methods in custom Sonar rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873804/proper-way-for-getting-annotations-of-java-methods-in-custom-sonar-rules)?

I use 3.7.1 of sonar-java-plugin and 5.1 of sonar-plugin-api.

Do you have any hint for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use semantic API for this. On the identifier you want to check (here in your case `field` that you should access via the memberSelectExpression) get the associated symbol using `symbol()` method of `IdentifierTree`.

On the returned symbol you can use the `isPackageVisibility()` method to determine the visibility of this field (you also have a bunch of other methods to work on the symbol).

Comment: Unfortunately this hint did not help to solve the Problem.
The `UnexpectedAccessCheckTest` from https://github.com/arxes-tolina/sonar-plugins/  fails because of this failing case: `UnexpectedAccessCheckTestClassCaller.defaultAccesMember()`  acceses some fields  (callee.visibleForAll) and (callee.visibleForTesting). There are still some `!unknownSymbol!` in the debug output to see.